# GD/PHP Adicionar texto pelo formulário / Fundo Transparente

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

    //Fundo Transparente
    imagealphablending($image, false);
    $transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparency);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);

    //Aproveitando
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 174, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($image, 25, 25, 75, 75, $black);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
?>
```

Eu quero adicionar um formulário com apenas um campo input, quando clicar no botão submit gerar uma imagem com fundo transparente com o conteúdo que escreveu no campo input.

Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer?

Answer (score 0):

aqui vai um exemplo:

```
<form action="proccessImage.php" method="post">
    Input: <input type="text" name="input1"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Quando clicares no botão sera feita uma requisição post ao arquivo **proccessImage.php**, onde depois podes adicionar o teu codigo para processar a imagem

tambem podes obter o valor do Input fazendo o seguinte:

```
$input1 = $_POST['input1'];
```